# Como fazer upload de uma imagem através da área de transferência (copiar e colar)?

Tags: javascript, imagem, upload, área-de-transferência

Eu estava dando uma olhada na funcionalidade do site [Imgur](https://imgur.com/). Quando você faz um printscreen ou mesmo copia uma imagem (não o link, mas a imagem, que é uma opção que está disponível na maioria dos navegadores atuais) e, em seguida, cola na página, é feito o upload da imagem que estava salva na área de transferência (clipboard).

Eu não faço a mínima ideia de como o Javascript pode ter acesso à essa parte da memória onde foi salvo o "Copiar".

Eu gostaria de uma demonstração simples de como posso fazer para transferir a imagem da memória e enviar através do upload. E também gostaria de saber se é possível transferir o conteúdo da área de transferência (CTRL+C) para um Blob do Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando algo é colado em uma página, o `js` dispara um evento na função **[onpaste](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste)**.

Quando colamos uma imagem, o `js` através da função `onpaste` nos retorna um objeto com a interface **[File](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/File)** *(Apenas no caso de binários, óbvio)*. Com esse objeto, nós podemos utilizar o método `getAsFile()` que utilizaremos com a classe `FileReader`.

Para ler esse conteúdo, podemos utilizar o método `readAsDataURL` da classe **[FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileReader)**. Com isso nós conseguimos capturar o código `base64` da imagem, e é basicamente isso que o código do site faz. Ele basicamente envia um `base64`, ao invés de um arquivo, para o servidor.

Segue um exemplo bem simples.

```js
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(result) {
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = result.target.result;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}

document.querySelector("input").onpaste = function(event){
  
  let items = event.clipboardData.items;

  for (itemIndex in items) {
      let item = items[itemIndex];

      if (item.kind == 'file') {
        reader.readAsDataURL(item.getAsFile());
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Cole sua imagem aqui" />
```

**Errata:** *Por que o Javascript precisa de um `for` pra achar a imagem?*

O `js` precisa desse `for` porque, quando você copia uma imagem da internet, é lançando uma ação no `onpaste` com dois [DataTransferItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem).

O primeiro item é um código `html` com um elemento `<img>`. Nesse elemento recebemos um código `base64` ou a URL da imagem. Por isso você está recebendo um `text/html` *(Você também pode receber um `text/plain`)*.

O segundo, já é uma imagem em si. Podendo ser capturada através do método `DataTransferItem.getAsFile()`

Comment: Bacana, cara. Simples e direto. +1

Comment: Eu só tenho uma dúvida: Por que o Javascript precisa de um `for` pra achar a imagem? Estranhamente num código que fiz semelhante ao seu, o valor `0` da iteração sempre traz um `item` com o valor `text/html` no `type` ou vazio, kkkkk...

Comment: Quando copia um arquivo da web, ao invés de vir o binário, ele como html. Fiz uma alteração que "burla" isso.

Comment: Inconformado com meu código, pesquisei um pouco mais e, fazendo alguns testes adicionais, encontrei uma resposta "descente" para a pergunta acima.