# Recuperar arquivo do input para passar como data no AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual, por questões de estética precisei recriar alguns elementos para poder personalizar corretamente cada especialmente `<select>` e `<option>`.

Então preciso passar o formulário captando a data manualmente. Para isso, estou usando:

```
  $('#criarConta').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "empregador.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      nome:       $('#nomeSign').val(),
      email:      $('#emailSign').val(),
      senha:      $('#passSign').val(),
      local:      $('#localInput').val(),
      site:       $('#siteInput').val(),
      tipo:       $('#tipoPerfil').data('selected'),
      ramo:       $('ramoInput').data('selected'),
      profilepic: $('profilePicInput').val()
    },
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
    });
  });
```

Coloquei esse `profilepic` aí pra verem onde eu pretendo chamar a imagem. Até onde sei, o `.val()` só vai recuperar o path do arquivo, não ele em si.

Como resolver meu caso?

Comment: Voce precisa criar um formdata para enviar a imagem, da uma olhada neste stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: Você quer enviar uma server o `arquivo/file`?

Comment: @LuizPillon E posso criar um form data sem a presença de um form? Como ficaria no meu exemplo (adicionando manualmente)?

Comment: @Marconi eu quero passar como post a imagem, juntamente com o restante dos elementos. Eu faço uma validação da imagem enviada no meu PHP, posteriormente.

Comment: `let form = new FormData(); form.append("campo", $('#input').val()); form.append("file", $("input2").prop('files')[0]);`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr posta uma resposta :)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr funcionou perfeitamente! Ainda por cima me deixa validar mais facilmente as checkbox! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar uma imagem, você pode utilizar o [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData). Essa é uma API serve justamente para armazenar valores que serão enviados via POST.

Quando você utiliza essa API, você está basicamente utilizando o `enctype: multipart/form-data`

Porém é necessário saber outro ponto, dessa vez com o `jQuery.ajax`. Por padrão o `jquery` transforma o valor de `data` para `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, então você terá que informar que **não** deseja utilizar esse padrão.

Quando você não está trabalhando com envio de arquivos, legal, não há problemas, mas no caso de uplaods é necessário adicionar essa informação: `processData:false,`

Agora vamos falar sobre o input. Como capturar o arquivo e não o `fake path`?

Diferente dos `input:text`, por exemplo, o `input:file` há um atributo a mais. O atributo `file` é responsável por armazenar em um array, todos os arquivos objetos do tipo [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) dentro de um [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).

Esse objeto — `file` — nada mais que um [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) (arquivo bruto) e é ele que será enviado para o servidor.

> No caso de imagens, você pode utilizar esse objeto para exibir uma thumbnail ou até mesmo [capturar a imagem utilizando o Ctrl + V](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267878/como-fazer-upload-de-uma-imagem-atrav%C3%A9s-da-%C3%A1rea-de-transfer%C3%AAncia-copiar-e-colar/267891#267891)

```
$('#criarConta').click(function(){     
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append("nome", $("#nome").val());
    form.append("file", $('#imagem').prop('files')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "index3.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: form,
        cache : false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Ah, e o `value`, no `input:file` exibe apenas um `C:\fakepath` para evitar que você tenha acesso a estrutura de pastas do usuário.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema.